# Can the manifest file be dynamic in Chrome Apps?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I am writing a Chrome App that communicate with a web page. For that I have added something similar in my manifest file.

```
"externally_connectable": {
  "matches": ["*://*.example.com/*"]
}
```

But the "example.com" has to be dynamic as individual customers has their one web server.

Is there any possibility, user(who install the app) can change the externally_connectable site/s.

Comment: No. It cannot be edited once extension is packed/installed. And there is no API to set the domains in script either.

Comment: I guess you'll have to change the communication architecture and use content scripts injected dynamically when the URL matches configured value saved in local storage of the extension.

Comment: Moni Do you have any alternative suggestions to address my issue

Comment: Have you found a working solution with this?

Comment: @Mouneer no I haven't and it seems you cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an alternative way a web page can communicate with extension through content script. This approach can be used if both web page and extension are  done by you.

E.g.

> web page <--> content script of extension <--> background script of
>   extension <--> native application

For web page to content script of extension communication use `window.postMessage` and `window.addEventListener`

For Google Chrome browser,

For content script of extension to background script of extension communication use `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` and `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener`

For background script of extension to native application communication use `chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage`

Please make sure your code has necessary security in place.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the `"externally_connectable"` is the only official way to send messages (With data) from a web page as mentioned [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage)

This requires a predefined values for every single domain. But what if you want to make only one extension to accept messages from any web page?

If you just want to notify the other side about some thing, you can use the native `JS Event` dispatching it on the `document` from one side and listening to it at `document` also from the other side as the `document` is shared between the extension `content script` pages and the web page.

You can't use `JS CustomEvent` to send data as every time you send data, you receive it empty as a result of `sandbox` effect of any extension.

If you want to share data so the only workaround I know so far - after spending about one month developing an extension - is to have a combination between some sort of a storage and the `JS` native Event mechanism.

The solution in steps (suppose you need the web page to send some data to the extension):

1. Make an event on `document` from the web page.
2. Save the data temporarily inside any storage technology you prefer
   (localStorage, the DOM itself, or what ever..)
3. Receive the event at the other side (extension) by listening on the
   `document`.
4. Read data and remove it.

Hope this helps someone or open a door for a discussion on a better way doing this.